# Excel - bottom border if text is present?

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, border

I'm creating an invoice at the moment, and there's going to be varying amounts of text on each invoice.

Ideally I'd like to be able to enter content, and as soon as I do that, it'll create a border along the bottom of that row, from A to K if that makes sense.

Is this possible?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not strictly programming... you can select the cells from A1 to Kn then go to Format > Conditional Formatting. Select "Formula Is", enter =$A1<>"". Click format and set the border.

Now if you enter a text to a cell in col. A, that row will be underlined up to column K. Not being familiar with invoices I can only hope this is what you wanted :)

Comment: This looks great, thanks Zed! Just wondering is there anyway to apply this rule to multiple rows at once?

Comment: Sure, you can select multiple rows (that's what A1 to Kn meant :)). Select the whole area, and enter the formula.

Comment: Ah hah! Excel does it for you, very clever and a great solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Conditional formatting might do the trick for you:

[Example #1](http://www.contextures.com/xlcondformat03.html)
[Example #2](http://www.wikihow.com/Apply-Conditional-Formatting-in-Excel)

In your case, (if I understand you right) you would highlight all cells from A1 to K10 (assuming a maximum of ten rows), and then make the conditional formatting formula as follows:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)),ISBLANK(A2))
```

Then just apply the border by setting it up in the "Format..." options as shown in the examples.