# Conditional Formatting to Border Overflow Text

Tags: excel, border, overflow, conditional-formatting

Like my title says, I need a formula for conditional formatting that will apply my specified border on cells that contain overflow text. Is this possible?

I have a formula that applies a border to cells that contain text, and it works great, but the border won't extend to a cell that has overflow text in it.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel - bottom border if text is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316573/excel-bottom-border-if-text-is-present)

Comment: I think they want the border to the right of overflowing text.  You could use `len(reference of last cell containing text)` and then calculate how many columns the text will overflow into based on column size and number of characters.  possibly change to a mono-spaced font to make it easier to calculate the size.  It will be complicated so can you not simply resize the column to the content width.

Comment: Bump. Does anyone have a suggestion for this? Unless I'm misunderstanding Gordon's suggestion, its not really an "automated" type of formula. I'm looking for something that uses conditional formatting, perhaps, that borders all cells with overflow text automatically (if such a thing exists...)

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1: The simple solution

Using Gordon's idea, if you use a mono-spaced font (like Courrier New for instance), you could count the number of characters it takes to overflow the cell and use the number of characters in the cells (via the `LEN` function) to create your conditional formatting.

For example, if you are using **Courrier New** with size 11 and regular column width (8.43, 64 pixels), you could fit 6 characters before the cell overflows.

[image]

So the conditional formatting formula would look like this:

```
=LEN(B2)>6
```

---

#### Option 2 : The more sophisticated solution

You could create a VBA function that determines the pixel width of the text in the cell using the method provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27424441/5958842) and then compare it with the column width in pixels. Then return TRUE if TextWidth > ColumnWidth.

```vb
Public Function DetectOverflowTextWidth(c As Range) As Boolean

    'Get column size in pixels
    Dim ColumnWidth  As Long
    ColumnWidth = (c.EntireColumn.Width / 72) * c.Parent.Parent.WebOptions.PixelsPerInch
    
    'Get Text size in pixels
    Dim TextWidth As Long
    TextWidth = GetStringPixelWidth(c.Value2, c.font.Name, c.font.Size, c.font.Bold, c.font.Italic)
    
    If ColumnWidth < TextWidth Then DetectOverflowTextWidth = True

End Function
```

And to have the pixel width of the text you'd have to include this in a (seperate) module:

```
Option Explicit

'API Declares

#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function CreateDC Lib "gdi32" Alias "CreateDCA" (ByVal lpDriverName As String, ByVal lpDeviceName As String, ByVal lpOutput As String, lpInitData As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function CreateCompatibleBitmap Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function CreateFontIndirect Lib "gdi32" Alias "CreateFontIndirectA" (lpLogFont As LOGFONT) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function SelectObject Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByVal hObject As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function DeleteObject Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hObject As LongPtr) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetTextExtentPoint32 Lib "gdi32" Alias "GetTextExtentPoint32A" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz As String, ByVal cbString As Long, lpSize As FNTSIZE) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function MulDiv Lib "kernel32" (ByVal nNumber As Long, ByVal nNumerator As Long, ByVal nDenominator As Long) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr) As Long
    
#Else
    Private Declare Function CreateDC Lib "gdi32.dll" Alias "CreateDCA" (ByVal lpDriverName As String, ByVal lpDeviceName As String, ByVal lpOutput As String, lpInitData As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleBitmap Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CreateFontIndirect Lib "gdi32.dll" Alias "CreateFontIndirectA" (lpLogFont As LOGFONT) As Long
    Private Declare Function SelectObject Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function DeleteObject Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetTextExtentPoint32 Lib "gdi32.dll" Alias "GetTextExtentPoint32A" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal lpsz As String, ByVal cbString As Long, lpSize As FNTSIZE) As Long
    Private Declare Function MulDiv Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal nNumber As Long, ByVal nNumerator As Long, ByVal nDenominator As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Const LOGPIXELSY As Long = 90

Private Type LOGFONT
    lfHeight As Long
    lfWidth As Long
    lfEscapement As Long
    lfOrientation As Long
    lfWeight As Long
    lfItalic As Byte
    lfUnderline As Byte
    lfStrikeOut As Byte
    lfCharSet As Byte
    lfOutPrecision As Byte
    lfClipPrecision As Byte
    lfQuality As Byte
    lfPitchAndFamily As Byte
    lfFaceName As String * 32
End Type

Private Type FNTSIZE
    cx As Long
    cy As Long
End Type


Private Sub test()

    MsgBox (GetStringPixelWidth("Test String", "Calibri", 10))
    MsgBox (GetStringPixelWidth(" ", "Calibri", 10, True, False))

End Sub  

Public Function GetStringPixelHeight(text As String, fontName As String, fontSize As Single, Optional isBold As Boolean = False, Optional isItalics As Boolean = False) As Integer

    Dim font As New StdFont
    Dim sz As FNTSIZE
    font.Name = fontName
    font.Size = fontSize
    font.Bold = isBold
    font.Italic = isItalics

    sz = GetLabelSize(text, font)
    GetStringPixelHeight = sz.cy

End Function


Public Function GetStringPixelWidth(text As String, fontName As String, fontSize As Single, Optional isBold As Boolean = False, Optional isItalics As Boolean = False) As Integer

    Dim font As New StdFont
    Dim sz As FNTSIZE
    font.Name = fontName
    font.Size = fontSize
    font.Bold = isBold
    font.Italic = isItalics

    sz = GetLabelSize(text, font)
    GetStringPixelWidth = sz.cx

End Function


Private Function GetLabelSize(text As String, font As StdFont) As FNTSIZE

#If VBA7 Then
    Dim tempDC As LongPtr
    Dim tempBMP As LongPtr
    Dim f As LongPtr
#Else
    Dim tempDC As Long
    Dim tempBMP As Long
    Dim f As Long
#End If


    Dim lf As LOGFONT
    Dim textSize As FNTSIZE

    On Error GoTo CleanUp

    ' Create a device context and a bitmap that can be used to store a
    ' temporary font object
    tempDC = CreateDC("DISPLAY", vbNullString, vbNullString, ByVal 0)
    tempBMP = CreateCompatibleBitmap(tempDC, 1, 1)

    ' Assign the bitmap to the device context
    DeleteObject SelectObject(tempDC, tempBMP)

    ' Set up the LOGFONT structure and create the font
    lf.lfFaceName = font.Name & chr$(0)
    lf.lfHeight = -MulDiv(font.Size, GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(0), 90), 72) 'LOGPIXELSY
    lf.lfItalic = font.Italic
    lf.lfStrikeOut = font.Strikethrough
    lf.lfUnderline = font.Underline
    If font.Bold Then lf.lfWeight = 800 Else lf.lfWeight = 400
    f = CreateFontIndirect(lf)

    ' Assign the font to the device context
    DeleteObject SelectObject(tempDC, f)

    ' Measure the text, and return it into the textSize SIZE structure
    GetTextExtentPoint32 tempDC, text, Len(text), textSize

CleanUp:    
    ' Clean up (very important to avoid memory leaks!)
    DeleteObject f
    DeleteObject tempBMP
    DeleteDC tempDC
    ' Return the measurements
    GetLabelSize = textSize

End Function
```

Finally, you'd use `DetectOverflowTextWidth` inside your custom conditional formatting formula to determine if the conditional formatting is applied.

**Disclaimer:** Option 2 is using certain Windows API functions and this could lead to memory leaks if not handled properly. I've added some error handling to the original answer to reduce the risks of it being a problem, but it's still something to keep in mind.